# Ternary condition using Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, plugins

I am using the [star rating plugin](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm) and i want to set the value of `data-rateit-readonly` based on certain condition i.e

```
  data-rateit-readonly="@Request.IsAuthenticated?(@Model.HasRatedOnAccuracy?true:false):true"
```

but it gives me

```
data-rateit-readonly="True?(False?true:false):true"
```

but i want if the Request id authenticated then it should check whether the user has already rated or not at the end the final html should look like either

```
data-rateit-readonly="true"
```

or

```
data-rateit-readonly="false"
```

please help me solve this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the multi-token syntax support (broken apart for readability):

```
data-rateit-readonly="@(Request.IsAuthenticated ? (
    Model.HasRatedOnAccuracy ? true : false
) : true)"
```

Comment: tnx for the answer that solved the problem well most of it... the remaining problem is it evaluates to `False` instead of `false` can something be done of it

Comment: @John - Wrap everything in another set of () and tack on ToString().ToLower();